# How to make an object available in all packages java spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, bugsnag

Following is my class, I want **Client object** to available in all packages with out going into each class and initialize. Also please suggest best available method to accomplished this.
using beans or anything available, I'm new to this.
I'm using java spring framework.

```
public class BSService
{

Client bSClient;

private String bSApiKey = "api_key";


public BSService()
{
    this.bSClient = new Client( bSApiKey );
}


public Client getBSClient()
{
    return this.bSClient;
}
}
```

Comment: by default any object is available every where .you need to just refer it by @Autowire annotation after defining in xml file.

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians - Thanks, can you mention the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

below is the summerised code-

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>


    <bean id="myservice1" class="service.MyServiceImpl1"></bean>
    <bean id="myservice2" class="service.MyServiceImpl2"></bean>
   <bean id="mydao" class="dao.MyDaoImpl"></bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

and refer them in controller class-

```
@Controller

public class MyController {
    @Autowired

    MyService myServiceImpl2;

}
```

Now `myServiceImpl2` will refer to bean object.

Answer (score 0):

An object of ServletContext is created by the web container at time of deploying the project. This object can be used to get configuration information from web.xml file. There is only one ServletContext object per web application. 
The context-param element, subelement of web-app, is used to define the initialization parameter in the application scope. The param-name and param-value are the sub-elements of the context-param. The param-name element defines parameter name and and param-value defines its value.

```
<web-app>
 ......

  <context-param>
    <param-name>parametername</param-name>
    <param-value>parametervalue</param-value>
  </context-param>
 ......
</web-app>
```